# How can I achieve the typesetting of this exercise sheet with a double bar left of the exercise?

Tags: formatting, exercises

I would like you to help me to get this forme for my exercises[image]

Comment: It depends if you are doing it yourself or using a package.  Easiest would be of overlap the \rule using \smash or \raisebox and \llap, although you still need to calculate or guess the depth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following `tcolorbox`-based approach might serve as a place to start from:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{most}


\newtcolorbox[auto counter,
              number within=chapter,
              list inside=myexercise
              ]{myexercise}[1][]{%
    enhanced,
    title={\textsc{Exercice}~\thetcbcounter.},
    #1,
    halign title=left,
    sharp corners,
    colback=white,
    coltitle=black,
    colbacktitle=white,
    boxrule=0pt,frame hidden,
    overlay unbroken={%
      \draw[black,double] (interior.north west)--(interior.south west);%
      },
    boxed title style={%
      colframe=white, 
      boxrule=0pt,
      colback=white,
      left=0pt,
      right=0pt},
    attach boxed title to top left={xshift={-5pt}},
}


\begin{document}


\chapter{Chapter title}

\begin{myexercise}
An example exercice.
\end{myexercise}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your precious help, however i'm getting the following error :Lonely \item--perhaps a missing list environment. \item $ when i use the environment \begin{multicols}.

Comment: How exactly did you use the `multicols` environment. I can not reproduce the error message you get.

Comment: \begin{myexercie}                                                                                                                     \begin{multicols}{2]                                                                                                                        \item ...                                                                                                                              \item ...                                                                                                                      \end{multicols} \end{myexercice} and the errors msg

Comment: You can not use `\item` outside of an `enumerate` or `itemize` environment. If you want numbered, items, use `enumerate`. Example: `\begin{myexercise}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}
\item item one
\item item two
\item item three
\item item four
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\end{myexercise}`

Comment: The image in your question shows enumerated items but I don't see two columns. So why do you want to use `multicols` here?

Comment: Thank you for you help, i was trying this for another exercice. The problem is fixed now.